# Need to find the duration using query in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets

Have rfid attendance data in google sheet where it has in and out time.Need to have how many hours an employee had worked for a given day. Have used query statement and was able to pull out min and max for a given day.Struck at need to find the duration HH:MM worked

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AbcTQ8CdmPO7KjtMFPWc1QK7rVnf1q0K51U_WAMKlqw/edit?usp=sharing

Attached the google sheet do have a look at the query code in G1 need to find the duration in K column

`` QUERY(A:D,"Select A,B, Max(C), Min (C),Max(C)- Min (C) Group by A,B Label A 'Key',B 'Date',Max(C) 'Maximum', Min (C) 'Minimum', Max(C)- Min (C) `Duration`",0) ``

so how to find difference between hours in query statement of googlesheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query formula, Sheets provides an error message that seems to be about the labels, so delete the label clause

```
Label A 'Key',B 'Date',Max(C) 'Maximum', Min (C) 'Minimum', Max(C)- Min (C) `Duration`
```

Now, after deleting the label clause, Sheets provides another error, stating

> Can't perform the function difference on values that are not
>   numbers.

So the problem is that you can't subtract `Min(C)` from `Max(C)` because the value in C is a time, not a number.

I don't think there's a great way to fix this *within* your QUERY() formula, but we can fix the data in the spreadsheet so that it works. In Column E, use [`=VALUE()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094220) to convert the times from Column C into numbers. For example, E2 will be `=VALUE(C2)`.

Now we just need to use those new values in your query (instead of `Max(C)-Min(C)`, use `Max(E)-Min(E)`) and include the [format clause](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#format).

```
=QUERY(A:E,"Select A,B, Max(C), Min(C), Max(E)-Min(E) Group by A,B Label A 'Key',B 'Date',Max(C) 'Maximum', Min(C) 'Minimum', Max(E)-Min(E) 'Duration' Format Max(E)-Min(E) 'HH:mm'",0)
```

Comment: Thanks that did work after formating the E Column as numbers. But this data is being appended from a RFID machine. So plan to move this query to next sheet. Can this value formatting be done in query itself? above document link  has edit option

Comment: @Kanted I couldn't figure out how to do it within the query(). Depending on how you're populating the RFID table, you may be able to format the original values as numbers and then display them in datetime as part of your query() instead.